# Drop Duplicates from Pandas DF with Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, drop

I have a pandas df that looks like the below:

Current df:

| Case | Task | Text_Present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Email | Yes |
| 123 | Outreach | No |
| 456 | Session | No |
| 456 | Email | No |

I would like to drop duplicate cases, but based on a condition of the Text_Present field.

If there's a 'Yes' present, keep the record where 'Yes' is present. If there's no 'Yes' present (ex: Case 456), then keep one of the records for 456 - does not matter which one.

I'm basically looking to understand the % Yes to % No, but the math is off due to the fact that the cases are duplicated as a result of the Description field - since I want to count any case where there was a 'Yes' in any Task as just a 'Yes' overall for that case.

My goal output is:

| Case | Task | Text_Present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Email | Yes |
| 456 | Session | No |

Ultimately, I want to compare % Yes to % No in a simple barchart, but the duplication is resulting in inaccurate percentages.

As far as I can tell, df.drop only offers first and last.

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the values with respect to `Case` and `Text_Present`. Then you can drop the duplicates over `Case` column and keep the last ones. Since `"Yes"` comes after than `"No"` alphabetically, it will reside in last positions and will be kept:

```
>>> df.sort_values(["Case", "Text_Present"]).drop_duplicates("Case", keep="last")

   Case   Task Text_Present
0   123  Email          Yes
3   456  Email           No
```